Error: The method 'scheduleWarmUpFrame' isn't defined for the class 'PlatformDispatcher'
I am using Flutter 3.22.3
And I am frequently seeing
Error: The method 'scheduleWarmUpFrame' isn't defined for the class 'PlatformDispatcher'.
Each time I get this I need to do a Flutter Clean and rerun my Pub Get and Build Runner. It is a big waste of time.
I saw that the issue was opened and closed, but I do not see it fixed.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/148414
Downgrading to 3.19.6 seems to be the only way around this for me.
does anyone have any other solutions?
